# Trouble Installing Broadcom BCM43142 in debian 8.6

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, debian

I've made a complete reinstall of Debian 8.6 with XFCE DE on my notebook laptop as I've messed up with my previous install, and my  Broadcom BCM43142 WiFi isn't working. I searched Synaptic package manager for BCM43142. And found 3 packages.

1. broadcom-sta-common
2. broadcom-sta-dkms
3. broadcom-sta-source

Which one should I install? I haven't installed "linux-headers" as I didn't know what it does. I tried following Debian wiki in previous install but it lead to slow WiFi connection. And while troubleshooting that issue I messed up with some files which dropped me down directly to "grub rescue mode" upon next reboot.
Following is the output of  lspci | grep Network (In case it helps finding exact WiFi card details)

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Comment: If it worked for you, you should upvote and accept (tick the V-shaped symbol) @GAD3R 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to install and enable `bcm43142` driver on debian?

According to [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) , you can install the `bcm43142` as follows:

Edit your `sources.list`:

```
editor /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add the following line:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Update and install the `linux-headers`the required driver `broadcom-sta-dkms`:

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Unload the conflicting drivers:

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
```

Load the right module :

```
modprobe wl
```

**troubleshooting**

There are some issue using the BCM43142 on the `3.16` kernel version. To solve the problem , Install a newest kernel version from backports .

Add backports to your sources.list :

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Run `apt-cache search linux-image` then install it, e,g:

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
```

Restart and boot the `4.7` kernel then install the `bcm43142` driver.

Comment: My WiFi is enabled now. Thanks @gad3r!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with BCM43142 but I think you need `broadcom-sta-dkms`: the DKMS subsystem is a modern way to have source-only kernel modules distributed in a free OS.

The idea is that the package using the DKMS subsystem is able to get the necessary modules automatically built and properly registered—just when you install the package. To cite `apt show dkms`:

> Description: Dynamic Kernel Module Support Framework
>   DKMS is a framework designed to allow individual kernel modules
>   to be upgraded without changing the whole kernel.
>   It is also very easy to rebuild modules as you upgrade kernels.

Each package update triggers rebuilding and re-registering (and re-insertion, if possible) of the new version of the provided module(s).

Things like putting the compiled modules into the initrd is taken care of automatically, too (though you don't need this).